# Calling method in subclass with access to its super class

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

I am making a football game for Android.

I have a class Player. Player is extended by DefencivePlayer and OffensivePlayer. Each of these classes have a touch event implemented and they are all unique. I have another class, mover, which handles touches which has access to Player. (as seen below)

[image: FootballGameUML]

Player is always either a DefencivePlayer or an OffensivePlayer. I would like the functionality of being able to handle touches by simply calling Player.touch and, depending on which it were, the respective touch method would be called in DefencivePlayer or OffensivePlayer.

I believe my design of having the two classes extend the Player class is wrong because it does not ensure that there are sub classes.

Please help, I am really trying to get a good design here and don't want to hack anything.

Comment: The problem I was having was hesitation. The functionality I wanted was exactly how my program would have behaved if I would have tested it. I assumed that the methods in the sub classes would be ignored since they didn't need to exists. Thanks for all the extremely quick replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test - using your class diagram, I set up the three player classes and created a generic `ArrayList<Player>` list of Offensive and Defensive players. Printing out the results of this code:

```
players.add(new OffensivePlayer());
players.add(new DefensivePlayer());
players.add(new OffensivePlayer());
players.add(new OffensivePlayer());
players.add(new DefensivePlayer());

for(Player p: players)
    p.touch();
```

gave me this output:

```
Touched offensive player.
Touched defensive player.
Touched offensive player.
Touched offensive player.
Touched defensive player.
```

In other words, the different types of players were interpreted as subclasses, not just as an instance of `Player`.

From a design perspective, it might be worthwhile making `Player` an abstract class, thus ensuring that no plain `Player` objects are created, thus the `touch()` method will only be executed from an instance of a subclass of `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your current setup.

As long as `Touch()` method is `abstract` (making `Player` be declared as `abstract class Player`), or Player is defined as an `interface Player`, you will be able to use `player.Touch()` and ensure that the implemented method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Player.Touch()` `abstract`. This will ensure that subclasses will provide their own implementation.